# How can I run clean-up code in a Rust library?

Tags: static, rust, destroy

I am making an crossplatform terminal library. Because my library changes the state of the terminal, I need to revert all the changes that are made to the terminal when the process ends. I am now implementing this feature and thinking of ways how to restore to the original terminal state at the end.

I thought that a static variable is initialized when the program starts and that when the program ends this static variable will be destroyed. Since my static variable is a struct which has implemented the [`Drop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.22.1/std/ops/trait.Drop.html) trait, it would be dropped at the end of the program, but this is not the case  because the string "drop called" is never printed:

```
static mut SOME_STATIC_VARIABLE: SomeStruct = SomeStruct { some_value: None };

struct SomeStruct {
    pub some_value: Option<i32>,
}

impl Drop for SomeStruct {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("drop called");
    }
}
```

Why is `drop()` not called when the program ends? Are my thoughts wrong and should I do this another way?

Comment: See [RFC - Allow Drop types in statics/const functions](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1440) and (slightly outdated) https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/static-items.html

Comment: So as the docs say: &quot;Statics may not contain any destructors.&quot;, how should I then run some code when the proccess ends. I think I can make it work but any suggestions?

Comment: See also: [How to make a Rust singleton's destructor run?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39426452/155423).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to enforce initialization and clean-up code in a library is to introduce a `Context` type that can only be constructed with a public `new()` function, and implementing the `Drop` trait. Every function in the library requiring initialization can take a `Context` as argument, so the user needs to create one before calling these functions.  Any clean-up code can be included in `Context::drop()`.

```
pub struct Context {
    // private field to enforce use of Context::new()
    some_value: Option<i32>,
}

impl Context {
    pub fn new() -> Context {
        // Add initialization code here.
        Context { some_value: Some(42) }
    }
}

impl Drop for Context {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        // Add cleanup code here
        println!("Context dropped");
    }
}

// The type system will statically enforce that the initialization
// code in Context::new() is called before this function, and the
// cleanup code in drop() when the context goes out of scope.
pub fn some_function(_ctx: &Context, some_arg: i32) {
    println!("some_function called with argument {}", some_arg);
}
```

Comment: Marked your answer because it is an way of solving the problem.

Answer (score 7):

One of the principles of Rust is [**no life before main**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.4.0/complement-design-faq.html#there-is-no-life-before-or-after-main-(no-static-ctors/dtors)), which implies *no life after main*.

There are considerable challenges in correctly ordering constructors and destructors before or after main. In C++ the situation is referred to as [static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order), and while there are work-arounds for it, its pendant (static destruction order fiasco) has none.

In Rust, the challenge is exacerbated by the `'static` lifetime: running a destructor in statics could lead to observing partially destructed *other* statics. Which is unsafe.

In order to allow safe destruction of statics, the language would need to introduce subsets of `'static` lifetimes to order the construction/destruction of statics while having those lifetimes still be `'static` from inside `main`...

---

**How to run code at the start/end of the program?**

Simply run code at the start/end of `main`. Note that any structure built at the beginning of `main` will be dropped at its end in reverse order of construction.

**And if I am not writing `main` myself?**

Ask the writer of `main`, nicely.

Comment: Thanks for the information, makes sense. Since I am writing an library maybe asking the user to execute some function from my library at the could be a thing. I'll have to think about it.