# Is there a way to execute a teardown function after all tests have been run?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, rust, integration-testing, teardown

In Rust, is there any way to execute a teardown function after **all** tests have been run (i.e. at the end of `cargo test`) using the standard testing library?

I'm not looking to run a teardown function after **each** test, as they've been discussed in these related posts:

- [How to run setup code before any tests run in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58006033/how-to-run-setup-code-before-any-tests-run-in-rust)
- [How to initialize the logger for integration tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177845/how-to-initialize-the-logger-for-integration-tests)

These discuss ideas to run:

- setup before **each** test
- teardown before **each** test (using [`std::panic::catch_unwind`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.catch_unwind.html))
- setup before **all** tests (using [`std::sync::Once`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Once.html))

One workaround is a shell script that wraps around the `cargo test` call, but I'm still curious if the above is possible.

Comment: I tried that but couldn't get it to work. Something like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8224db31fdf2f2ef099e313d937bfcde), maybe?

Comment: you can make a script I think like `build.rs`, you must probably configure a profil

Comment: You are right, destructors aren't run for static variables – see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48732387/how-can-i-run-clean-up-code-in-a-rust-library as well.

Comment: There's an accepted experimental RFC to allow custom test frameworks – see [this tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/50297). This would allow a lot more flexibility around tests, but unfortunately there hasn't been much progress on this yet.

Comment: As @SvenMarnach, I think that there is no solution to this issue unless this RFC is implemented. If you use the nightly compiler, you can do that with the few that was implemented AFAIK

Comment: People often use trybuild (https://docs.rs/trybuild/1.0.18/trybuild/) for testing procedural macros, and I'm fairly certain you can actually apply this crate to any use case, even custom testing framework, if you must. Maybe if someone built such thing on top of this, the RFC mentioned above might even move forward?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example implementation of the custom test framework solution mentioned by Masklinn:

```rust
#![feature(custom_test_frameworks)]
#![feature(test)]
#![test_runner(custom_test_runner)]

extern crate test;

use test::{test_main_static, TestDescAndFn};

fn main() {}

pub fn custom_test_runner(tests: &[&TestDescAndFn]) {
    println!("Setup");
    test_main_static(tests);
    println!("Teardown");
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {

    #[test]
    fn test1() {
        println!("Test 1")
    }

    #[test]
    fn test2() {
        println!("Test 2")
    }
}
```

This will print:

```
Setup
Test 1
Test 2
Teardown
```

Comment: It's still unstable, but this would be definitely an upgrade from the status quo.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure there's a way to have a global ("session") teardown with Rust's built-in testing features, [previous inquiries seem to have yielded little](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59077877/rust-teardown-function-after-all-tests), aside from "maybe a build script". Third-party testing systems (e.g. shiny or stainless) might have that option though, might be worth looking into their exact capabilities

Alternatively, if nightly is suitable [there's a custom test frameworks feature being implemented](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/50297), which [you might be able to use for that purpose](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/language-features/custom-test-frameworks.html).

That aside, you may want to look at `macro_rules!` to cleanup some boilerplate, that's what folks like burntsushi do [e.g. in the regex package](https://github.com/rust-lang/regex/blob/master/tests/macros.rs).

Comment: when linking to "previous inquiries have yielded little" you linked to this question .

Comment: Link is dead...